# Flask - Stream content keeping context

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am using the folllowing Flask code to stream the output of a command:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        # some logic to get cmd from POST request
        ...
        return redirect_to(url_to(stream, cmd=cmd))
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stream/<cmd>')
def stream(cmd):
    print("Executing %s" % cmd)
    g = proc.Group()
    p = g.run(cmd)
    def stream_cmd():
        while g.is_pending():
            lines = g.readlines()
            for proc, line in lines:
                print(line)
                yield line + '</br>'
    return Response(stream_cmd(), mimetype='text/html')  # text/html is required for most browsers to show th$
```

When I post my form, it redirects to a blank page where I see the output of my stream but I loose all my layout / css / html / etc ...

**How can I keep the current layout in place while still seeing a streamed output ?**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to update a `<div>` element in the current page (instead of redirect) with the stream output dynamically (Jquery), but I'm not sure that's even possible.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/

Comment: but honestly this is better done with Server Sent Events / websockts

Comment: Could you provide some code to do this with a websocket ? I see that everywhere but I never got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @reptilicus recommendation, I rewrote the code to use websockets.

Here is the working code:

**Python**

```
@socketio.on('message', namespace='/stream')
def stream(cmd):
    # Streams output of a command
    from shelljob import proc
    g = proc.Group()
    p = g.run(cmd)
    while g.is_pending():
        lines = g.readlines()
        for proc, line in lines:
            send(line, namespace='/stream')
            eventlet.sleep(0) # THIS IS MANDATORY
```

The corresponding JavaScript that receives those messages sent by `send` calls is as follow:

**JavaScript (JQuery)**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/stream')

socket.on('message', function(msg){
  $('#streaming_text').append(msg);
})

...

jqxhr.done(function(cmd){ # This is executed after an AJAX post, but you can change this to whatever event you like
  socket.send(cmd)
  return false; 
})
```